# Solr to Tokenize on white space, comma and period

Tags: solr, solrnet, solr4

I am trying to force Solr to tokenize document on white-space, comma,  `:` and `;`. Something similar to what SQL Server Full Text search does. If I use `text_general` field then it tokenizes on other characters as well like `('/','\','-')` , I tried using

```
<tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\s*,:;\s*"/>
```

But it doesn't tokenize it. Here is how my `FieldType` looks like:

```
<fieldType name="text_sqlserver" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\s*,:;\s*"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\s*,:;\s*"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Is there anything that I am missing ? I have to search for case insensitive comparison as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your pattern is actually wrong, try something like this instead :
`pattern="[\s,;:]"`

An alternative you might want to try :

- [`PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory) (to replace `,` `:` `;` with whitespace)
- [`WhitespaceTokenizerFactory`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory) which tokenizes on whitespace and offers interesting options.

Comment: Do you know how could I add `<` and `>` in pattern, I can't specify that in XML because of XML rules, if I use `&gt;`, `&lt;` it doesn't seem to tokenize it

Comment: `&lt;` and `&gt;` are parsed as `<` and `>` by Solr so you're right about that. However, `<` and `>` have to be escaped in a regex pattern to be considered as literals, so just try : `\&lt;` `\&gt;` (haven't tested yet)